# How I make excel show a await message while execute a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that consulte to Database (in this case is a excel workbook), but when the macro consulte to database, it take 30 sec, and the user thinks that the program is broke. I tried with "Application.StatusBar = "Refresh File. "", but the user can´t see the sentence, the best way is a msgbox with the message "Await a moment", and, when the macro is finished, this message is closed. Do you help me with the code? I think the solution is this way:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
'Call msgbox with message "Await a moment"
Dim x As Long
For x = 0 To 2000000000 Step 1
Next
'The msgbox is closed
End Sub
```

I think the solution is a msgbox but it is a another option, Go Ahead!

Comment: Brax has given nice options below. A 3rd One, Create a form and show it modally `AndAlso` move the entire process in the `Activate` event of the form. This way users will not be able to interact with the workbook as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Msgbox wont work, because it would stop execution of everything until the user clicks OK.

The statusbar would work, if you put a `DoEvents` right after you set it so the system has a moment to update the screen.

Your only other option would be to create a special form that you show while it's processing, but you would also need a `DoEvents` after you show it as well.

```
Sub Test()
  ' create a userform and name it frmWait
  ' put whatever you want on that form
  ' that is what will be displayed while the user waits

  frmWait.Show vbModeless
  DoEvents

  ' do your processing here

  Unload frmWait
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Sub Test()
  Application.StatusBar = "Refreshing File. "
  DoEvents

  ' do your processing here

  ' reset the status bar to normal
  Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the answer, for other user that has the same problem and don´t know what is "frmWait", this is a UserForm that you create with a waiting message likes "Wait a moment please"